# Normalizing histogram of a data of size <39*31>?

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am quite new to Matlab. I am looking to calculate the pdf of a variable of size <39*31>?
I read we can do that by normalizing with area or sum but I am confused how to go with it?
Can anyone guide what step to follow?
Many thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `hist`

Answer (score 0):

Compute and plot the pdf of a multivariate normal distribution.

```
mu = [0 0];
Sigma = [.25 .3; .3 1];
x1 = -3:.2:3; x2 = -3:.2:3;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
F = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],mu,Sigma);
F = reshape(F,length(x2),length(x1));
surf(x1,x2,F);
caxis([min(F(:))-.5*range(F(:)),max(F(:))]);
axis([-3 3 -3 3 0 .4])
xlabel('x1'); ylabel('x2'); zlabel('Probability Density');
```

[image]

Example taken from: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/multivariate-normal-distribution.html

Answer (score 0):

assuming the variable contains some kind of frequency.
For a simple approach try this:

```
% just some test data 
var = abs(peaks(39));
var(1:2,:)=[];
size(var)

% the next line is the relevant code
pdf = var/sum(var(:));
surf(pdf)
```